# How to convert C code into code which uses fixed-size integer types?

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, long-integer

I'm currently working with C code which just uses `int` and `long` on 32 bit systems.
Now, I want to use fixed-size integer type for porting the application to 64 bit.

Is there a tool which can help me to replace the current data types with fixed-size integer types?

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

**EDIT**

I'm currently working with very old C code (~25 years old). The program is compiled and runs on 32 bit systems. The developers used normal data types so far (e.g. `int` and `long`).
But now, we want to get the application running as a 64 bit application. So, a good first step would be to replace the normal data types with fixed-size once.
Is there a tool with which I can do that automatically?

Input: c-file with normal types and current architecture information
Ouput: c-file with fixed-size integer types

Comment: Out of interest, why do you consider the fixed width stuff to be any better?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and tell us more. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You could use type definitions or precompiler definitions. As @Bathsheba pointed out, why not trust the compiler and let it use the actual architecture?... which is by the way always faster at run time.

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as writing something small to run through the code and replace the types with `_t` types?

Comment: @SvenKrüger If both max speed, and minimum guaranteed size are needed, there are these:  int_fast8_t int_fast16_t int_fast32_t int_fast64_t uint_fast8_t uint_fast16_t uint_fast32_t uint_fast64_t

Comment: "Why not trust the compiler?" - Because there are many situations where the actual bit size matters a great deal (for example unions and structs, working with binary files or protocols, working with low level hardware or registers). 
As an embedded programmer our Coding Standards require us to ALWAYS use the fixed width `uintN_t` types.

Comment: The developers round about 25 years ago decided to use the normal data types and not fixed-size once.
Now I want to replace them. Is there a tool which can help me to do that?

Comment: "Ctrl + h", replace all "int" with "int32_t"...

Comment: Depends on the code, but a global find/replace is likely to miss subtle corner cases. I've update my answer to cover this.

Comment: @SvenKrüger This would be very hard for ~500.000 lines of code.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: You may have worse problems: Std C library, and other libraries use int not (e.g. 32bit integers), so you will encounter other kind of bugs (wrong assumption of safe conversions). Usually it is easier just to assume that 32bit programs works on 64bit, just check the few exception that could cause problems (maybe just on IO parts). Old code does not mean bad code.

Comment: If you are using Intel x86 architecture, you can compile and run 32-bit programs without problem on 64bit machines. I think you are thinking that fix operand size will be the lazy and fast way to port a program to 64bit. I assure you: this is not the case. You will have much more problems.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for your hints. I know, this will be just a first step ... I suspect a huge amount of efforts until it is done.
The problem is that many 32bit libraries we are using are not supported anymore. That's why we want to "switch" to 64 bit.

Comment: @sealor, it is very hard to me that to accept that the 500K lines of code with 'int' on them will break if 'int' is bigger, specially because in 64 bits mode int is still 32 bits. Nevertheless, the approach should be to look for the areas of the code where the size of the type is assumed a particular size and change them for int32_t or int64_t as some other people suggested.

Comment: Please re-phrase your question, since tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 4):

`<stdint.h>` should define the following types:

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
```

Those are required by the C standard to be the stated fixed widths in bits.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html

In terms of *automatic* tools to do the replacement for you: I doubt you will get one that will work 100% accurately as there are lots of hard-to-detect corner cases to consider (bitwise operations, integer rollover, struct sizes, implicit casting etc).

I think your best bet would be to identify what areas of the code *require* fixed width integers and target those manually. Obviously you'll also want to  determine the normal width of `int`, `long` etc on your target platform so you know what to replace them with.

Comment: The __C__ Standard requires `<stdint.h>` to define those types *only if they are directly supported on the target architecture*.  POSIX goes further, but the question didn't specify that.  Consider alternatives such as the `int_leastX_t` and `int_fastX_t` families where the needs are not exact, and/or you need to compile for systems that don't support those integer widths.

Comment: More precisely, per **7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types**, paragraph 3 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): "These  types  are  optional.   However,  if  an  implementation  provides  integer  types  with
widths  of  8,  16,  32,  or  64  bits,  no  padding  bits,  and  (for  the  signed  types)  that  have  a
two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names."

Comment: In this instance I think we can assume the OPs system supports these types, as they are looking to convert an existing codebase to 64-bit. In reality the overwhelming majority of target architectures that most developers encounter will directly support these types.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to C99, use the [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) defined in `stdint.h`.

Otherwise, write the equivalent `typedef`s yourself.

As for tools to do so automatically, there cannot be any. It is impossible to know the original requirements from the source code, therefore, there is no way to do the replacement mechanically.

However, if you can identify some patterns that would need replacement, some tools might help to match them, like [semantic patches (Coccinelle)](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/sp.php).

Regardless of how you do it, you will need to prepare a proper way to test for regressions, since you can easily introduce subtle issues when changing types like this.

Answer (score 1):

Independently of why you want to use fixed types, yes, there two options there:

1. Include the standard header `<stdint.h>`, which defines fixed sizes independently of the compilation target: `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t` and so on...
2. Define them yourself using the preprocessor to detect compilation target.

I'll explain option 2 for the sake of people interested in advanced preprocessor handling:

If you include `<limits.h>`, a series of very useful macros wili be defined, e.g. `UINT_MAX`, which holds the maximum value that an unsigned integer can hold. Another is `ULONG_MAX`, which by now you should know that it holds. ;-)

So we will define `u32_t` and `u64_t` correctly in Windows and Unix/Linux by using the preprocessor. Look at the code twice and you will know what is doing.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char  u8_t;    // always 8 bits
typedef unsigned short u16_t;   // always 16 bits

#if (UINT_MAX < 0xFFFFFFFFU)    // Int is less than 32 bits

    #error "int should be 32 bits to compile this code"

#elif (UINT_MAX==0xFFFFFFFFU)   // Int is 32 bits

    typedef unsigned int u32_t;

    #if (ULONG_MAX==0xFFFFFFFFU) // long is also 32 bits

        #if defined(_WIN64) // In Windows 64 bits there is not long long
            typedef unsigned _int64     u64_t;
        #else
            typedef unsigned long long  u64_t;
        #endif

    #elif (ULONG_MAX==0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFU) // long is 64 bits

        typedef unsigned long   u64_t;

    #else

        #error "long should be 32 or 64 bits to compile this code"

    #endif

#else   // Int is bigger than 32 bits

    #error "int should be 32 bits to compile this code"

#endif


int main() 
{
    printf("int %lu bits, long %lu bits\n\n", (sizeof(int)*8),(sizeof(long)*8));
    printf("uint8_t  = %lu bits - u8_t  = %lu bits\n",(sizeof(uint8_t)*8),(sizeof(u8_t)*8));
    printf("uint16_t = %lu bits - u16_t = %lu bits\n",(sizeof(uint16_t)*8),(sizeof(u16_t)*8));
    printf("uint32_t = %lu bits - u32_t = %lu bits\n",(sizeof(uint32_t)*8),(sizeof(u32_t)*8));
    printf("uint64_t = %lu bits - u64_t = %lu bits\n",(sizeof(uint64_t)*8),(sizeof(u64_t)*8));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example in macOS:

```
macpro:code guille$ gcc -m64 types.c
macpro:code guille$ ./a.out 
int 32 bits, long 64 bits

uint8_t  = 8 bits - u8_t  = 8 bits
uint16_t = 16 bits - u16_t = 16 bits
uint32_t = 32 bits - u32_t = 32 bits
uint64_t = 64 bits - u64_t = 64 bits
macpro:code guille$ gcc -m32 types.c
macpro:code guille$ ./a.out 
int 32 bits, long 32 bits

uint8_t  = 8 bits - u8_t  = 8 bits
uint16_t = 16 bits - u16_t = 16 bits
uint32_t = 32 bits - u32_t = 32 bits
uint64_t = 64 bits - u64_t = 64 bits
macpro:code guille$
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would add that the only reason that you would define these types yourself, instead of just using `<stdint.h>`, would be where you need to support an ancient non-standards compliant compiler. 
And in most of those cases you would be better off just upgrading to a newer compiler!

Comment: Can you be sure that `long long` is always 64 bits whenever `long` is 32 bits?

Comment: TobySpeight its very unlikely that long long would be bigger than 64 bits if long is 32 because it would be compiling in ILP32. The only case of long long over 64 bits I have seen is when compiling in ILP64, and that is a very rare compilation mode. Besides @GrahamS is right and the only reason to do something like what I did is to support and old compiler, and the code would be rather different. I simplified to show what the preprocessor can do. I would advise to use option 1. ;-)